# Inserting data into a nested list in Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list like this:

```
list = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']]
```

I am trying to return a list like this where ' newdata' is added into every row in the second "column":

```
list = [['a1', 'a2 newdata', 'a3'], ['b1', 'b2 newdata', 'b3'], ['c1', 'c2 newdata', 'c3']]
```

What is best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering ' newdata' is a string, else you ll have to use str()

```
for item in list:
        item[1] += ' newdata'
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over your list you can do something like this:

```
for element in my_list:
  print element
```

And it will print all the elements in your list. It appears that every element inside your nested list is a string, therefore, to add a string to the 2nd element of that nested list you'd need to:

```
for element in my_list:
  print element[1] += ' newdata'
```

Remember, **index starts at 0**.
if 'newdata' isn't a string you'll need to use this as:

```
for element in my_list:
  print element[1] += ' ' + str(newdata)
```

This page might have more useful information on how to iterate over your list:

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop